# Reputation across other sites

Tags: support, reputation, stack-exchange

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Jenkins build actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523239/jenkins-build-actions)

There were lots of communities,Can we merge the reputation across other communities with stack over flow.

Comment: Reputation is a measure of how much the system trusts you. Since each site in the network has different rules, it doesn't make sense to merge reputation scores. There is an association bonus where you automatically get 100 rep across the network if you get 200 rep at any one site but that's just to get you past the comment and bounty thresholds.

Comment: Did you have a question about your post "[Jenkins build actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523239/jenkins-build-actions)"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Each site tracks reputation based on actions performed on that particular site.

However, if you have at least 200 reputation on any Network site, you will be granted an [association bonus](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/) to bypass new user restrictions when signing up for [another site on the Network](https://stackexchange.com/sites).